# Are X.509 nameConstraints on certificates supported on OS X?

Tags: certificates, macos, chrome, x.509

I have the following "chain" of certificates on a test machine right now:

- A self-signed CA cert, in my Keychain and trusted & trusted by Firefox.
- A CA cert with with the following,

  ```
  X509v3 Name Constraints: critical
    Permitted:
      DNS:mydomain.net
      DNS:.mydomain.net
  ```
- A non-CA cert with signed by the above.

The test webserver serves the latter two certs; the first is marked as "trusted" in Keychain in OS X, in Firefox itself, and on my Linux side, also in FF and by `certutil`.

On OS X, Firefox accepts the connection as secure; Chrome and Safari do not. It looks like Chrome & Safari just uses whatever the OS uses for crypto purposes, so here, OS X is the issue. Viewing the cert shows:

```
"This certificate cannot be used (unrecognized critical extension)"

Extension: Name Constraints (2.5.29.30)
 Critical: YES
     Data: <a sequence of octets>
```

I'm guessing because I'm seeing a sequence of octets, and *not* a nice decoded view (like I do with other extensions), that this is the extension causing the error.

I can't get it to work on Linux either under Chrome (works fine in FF, again); there, however, it doesn't seem to be able to find the root cert (whereas on OS X it can); I think this is because I don't understand how to accept my self-signed cert. (The Internet says `certutil`, and I've tried just about every combination of that to no avail.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#No. Apple does not support this.

Apple's [Secure Transport](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Reference/secureTransportRef/) library does not support X.509's [`nameConstraints`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.10).

There is a bug in Chromium's bug database about this. And it's been closed as `WontFix`.
Developer [Ryan Sleevi had this to say on Aug 25, 2014](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=407093) (archived [here](https://archive.is/6Clgb)):

> Chrome defers to the OS cryptographic stack for verification.

It's a well-known, long-standing issue that Apple does not implement name constraints. This applies to all applications that use OS X's SSL or certificate verification libraries (e.g. Safari, Curl, Python, etc)

#Related

- [Should name constraints be present on a subordinate CA issued to an organization?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/85272/should-name-constraints-be-present-on-a-subordinate-ca-issued-to-an-organization)
- [Which properties of a X.509 certificate should be critical and which not?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/30974/which-properties-of-a-x-509-certificate-should-be-critical-and-which-not)
- http://karl.kornel.us/2014/09/cas-name-constraints-and-a-business-opportunity/

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I'd have spent all day troubleshooting this if I hadn't found your note. Good work on the archived external confirmation too.

Comment: It looks like this may no longer be the case.  I can't find any useful developer documentation (and I don't have a Mac to test on), but iOS change notes at https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT208463 and macOS notes at https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT208465 mention fixing "A certificate evaluation issue ... in the handling of name constraints".  Can anyone confirm when this functionality was first added?

Comment: @JoeLee-Moyet: Good question! Dunno, I don't have an apple device handy to test. -- Apple's quote *"Impact: A certificate may have name constraints applied incorrectly"* certainly reads like name constraints ARE in fact supported.

Comment: There is now a public test suite available: https://nameconstraints.bettertls.com/

According to this, both Safari and Chrome on my Mac running macOS 10.15.4 support name constraints.

Answer (score 11):

## Yes, OS X / macOS supports this since 10.13.3.

According to the https://nameconstraints.bettertls.com archived tests, [10.13 failed some tests](https://nameconstraints.bettertls.com/#!view?results=safari_604_osx10) but 10.13.3 passes all in with both [Safari](https://nameconstraints.bettertls.com/#!view?results=safari_604_osx10.13.3) and [Chrome](https://nameconstraints.bettertls.com/#!view?results=chrome_63_osx10.13.3).

This fit's the timeline [release notes for macOS 10.13.3](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT208465) which lists the following fix<sup>1</sup>

> Description: A certificate evaluation issue existed in the handling of name constraints. This issue was addressed with improved trust evaluation of certificates.

Firefox who uses it's own internal TLS passes since [at least version 50](https://nameconstraints.bettertls.com/#!view?results=firefox_50_osx10).

This also matches [lxgr's comment about it working on 10.15.4](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/95600/are-x-509-nameconstraints-on-certificates-supported-on-os-x/97133#comment473143_97133) comment and my test today on 10.14.6

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>[as pointed out by Joe Lee-Moyet in the comments](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/95600/are-x-509-nameconstraints-on-certificates-supported-on-os-x/97133#comment436765_97133)</sup>